# Returning data from an activity to another activity's fragment?

Tags: java, android

How can I pass data between an activity and a fragment belonging to another activity? I think that it should be something similar to passing data between activities through intents, but I'm not able to figure it out and couldn't get any search result on it either.

For example, I have two activities A and B.

A has 3 fragments - "x", "y" and "z". Now I call B from "x" using startActivityForResult.

When I try and come back to "x" from "B" via setResult, it actually takes me to onActivityResult of "A" and not the one in "x...". Plus the requestCode and resultCode are some number (65536) and -1 respectively.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Fragment is art of activity so if you start another activity and return to previous then it will return to activity not fragment. if you want to pass data to fragment  then you can implement callback methods and pass data as argument to fragment .

Comment: Here you can see how to communicate between fragments: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely your parent activity inplements `onActivityResult()` too, but in that method you forgot to call `super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);` to pass unhandled request codes. Or you got request code clash and the same code is expeceted by parent activity and the fragment.

Comment: Wow, good heavens, thanks a lot! It works! I did forget to call super in my parents onActivityResult.